# recreate mysqld file centos

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I have tried installing mysql several times but keep getting this error:

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

I've tried:

```
yum remove mysql-server 
yum remove mysql
yum remove MySQL-*
```

then

```
yum install mysql-server 
yum install mysql 
yum install mysql-devel
```

and then both

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
service mysqld start
```

but keep getting that error.
Is there a way to recreate that file possibly?

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Comment: Running `/etc/init.d/mysqld start` returns "mysqld: unrecognized service"?  Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
yum install mysql 
yum install mysql-server 
yum install mysql-devel 
chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql 
chmod -R 770 /var/lib/mysql 
service mysqld start
```

It states in the ouptut of the last command to copy and paste mysql.server into the appropriate runlevel area for your install.

find the file mysql.server on the machine anywhere. Anyone know where it is or how to proceed?

It also states to set the passwords for your root account like so

/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password' 
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h hostname password 'new-password'

Answer (score 0):

you can download `mysqld` init script from other server or you can use below trick,

since yum unable to remove mysql-server because "/etc/init.d/mysqld" not exists, yum first try to stop using init script then it will remove package, so we just need to place any init script in that location for temporary as below:

```
 cp /etc/init.d/crond /etc/init.d/mysqld
```

then erase mysql-server package

```
yum erase mysql-server
```

next , install it again

```
yum install mysql-server
```

then check `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the mysql service manually and watch the output for what is going wrong. `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe`